# how to decode an hexacidemal values to binary ones with springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, binary, hex

i am a new developper
i don't know how to decode hexacidemal values to binary ones with springboot, Is There a default functions That can help me or should i develop functions by myself

Also ,i want to compare the result with another one , should the 2 values be String ?
thank You

Answer (score 0):

When you group 4 bits(1 bit is binary) it form a tuple which represent by one Hex decimal number.
There is no need of converting Hex to binary(in string format).

If you still want to do this you can refer:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-convert-hexadecimal-to-binary/